# Passing an Object Through a Storyboard Segue

Tags: ios, swift, object, storyboard, segue

I have the following segue in a `TableViewController` and each table row has a Fruit object. I want to pass each row's object to a view controller that shows more details about the object in a row, so I've written the segue below to transfer the Fruit object across view controllers.

In the `FruitDescriptionViewController`, I couldn't figure out how to define the variable that will take on the object from the row because it won't let me define a variable `var chosenFruit = Fruit` and in the segue, I get the error `cannot pass type Fruit to type Fruit.type`

How would I go about passing the Fruit object via segue and storing it in a Fruit variable in the `FruitDescriptionViewController`?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "FruitDetails" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                var fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
                let controller = segue.destination as? FruitDescriptionViewController
                controller?.chosenFruit = Fruit(name: fruit.name, url: fruit.url, fruitArray: fruit.fruitArray)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `var chosenFruit = Fruit` should be `var chosenFruit: Fruit?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is correct, you can set the object to the next viewController in the segue.

The problem here is not about the segue, but I believe it's in the `FruitDescriptionViewController`. You have a variable set like this:

```
var chosenFruit = Fruit
```

What you are doing here is saving the type Fruit to the variable `chosenFruit`. That's why when you try and set an instance of the Fruit type to chosenFruit it says `cannot pass type Fruit to type Fruit.type`. The variable has the type of the Fruit type and you are trying to set an instance.

What you should do instead is setting the choseFruit variable as the following:

```
var chosenFruit: Fruit? //or var chosenFruit: Fruit! if its necessary
```

This way, the type of the var would be correct.